# WCF with JSONP but not special properties

Tags: .net, wcf, jsonp, compatibility

I've got a WCF 4.5 service that needs to return JSON/JSONP. I can do this by using `WebScriptServiceHostFactory`, but that adds the `__type` special property to all objects and wraps the response in a `{d:{...}}` object. I don't want that.

I can get rid of it by using a `WebServiceHostFactory`, but that the doesn't support JSONP.

How do I achieve a clean JSONP output from WCF?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these attributes on your functions/methods?

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebGet(UriTemplate:="GetJobDetails?inpt={inpt}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
```

Comment: Those attributes won't affect whether JSONP is supported or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to enable the usage of JSONP with the webHttpBinding:

If you want to use the `WebServiceHostFactory`, you can change the default value for the `crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled` property in the *default* endpoint created by that factory. That can be done by adding the section below to your config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"
                              defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you don't want to change the default for *all* web service hosts in your application, then you can make the change for your application only. One alternative is to use a custom service host factory which will set the endpoint as needed:

```
    public class MyFactory : ServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        }

        class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
        {
            public MyServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
                : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
            {
            }

            protected override void OnOpening()
            {
                // this assumes the service contract is the same as the service type
                // (i.e., the [ServiceContract] attribute is applied to the class itself;
                // if this is not the case, change the type below.
                var contractType = this.Description.ServiceType;
                WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
                binding.CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true;
                var endpoint = this.AddServiceEndpoint(contractType, binding, "");
                var behavior = new WebHttpBehavior();
                behavior.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json;
                endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
            }
        }
    }
```

And yet another alternative would be to define the endpoint via configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="StackOverflow_14280814.MyService">
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="withJsonp"
                      behaviorConfiguration="web"
                      contract="StackOverflow_14280814.MyService" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="withJsonp" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: The < webHttp / > was key for us.